# flash If statement only working on the second time

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs5

I'm doing a page that checks for a typed answer and either says "correct" or "wrong" based on the response. The issue is that it works only in the second time.

I ask a question about world war 2 and the answer is 'hiroshima' no capital letters, but when i type it the first time i get "wrong" if i type it again it says it is correct.

any ideas of what im doing wrong?

this is my code which is trigger by an even listener on a button.

```
function examineTest(event:Event) : void{

    if (testPage.answerText.text=='hiroshima')
    {
        testPage.checkText.text="Correct!"
    }

    else

    {
        testPage.checkText.text="Sorry you enter the wrong answer"
        testPage.answerText.text=""
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible that there is some, maybe hidden, text in the `answerText.text` that doesnt get deleted until you do `testPage.answerText.text=""` ? Try setting it to `""` before the user gets a chance to enter text.

Comment: hi,thank you for replying. I did that (at least i think i did) and also when back to the text box and look for any spaces or anything and nothing was there. I still get the same error. I did add some new code to account for capital letters. but the issue still there.               function examineTest(event:Event) : void{
 
 testPage.answerText.text=""
 
 if ((testPage.answerText.text.toLowerCase()=='hiroshima'))
 {
 testPage.checkText.text="Correct!"
 }
 
 else
 
 {
 testPage.checkText.text="Sorry you enter the wrong answer"
 testPage.answerText.text=""
 }
}

Comment: Try `testPage.answerText.text.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf('hiroshima') == 0` for better string comparison. I suppose you could also check the `length`.

Comment: of course if you do: `function examineTest(event:Event) : void{ testPage.answerText.text="" if ((testPage.ans...` you have just set it to `""` before you compared it, I would think it would always be false.

Comment: your code worked (testPage.answerText.text.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf('hiroshima') == 0) thank you very much..this was driving me crazy all day and couldnt find any answers. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
testPage.answerText.text.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf('hiroshima') == 0
```

for better string comparison.

However, this will not guarantee the string is an exact match. As there could be additional characters at the end. Since you know `hiroshima` is 9 characters in length. You can then also check the `length`

```
testPage.answerText.text.length == 9
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001559.html and this whole site is your best resource